# Why would running as a cronjob cause an error on a python array index?

Tags: python, cron

I have a script that parses some weather data from weather.gov ([an example xml](https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdSOAPclientByDay.php?whichClient=NDFDgenByDay&lat=30.4261&lon=-91.1545&format=12+hourly&numDays=4&Unit=e)) and creates an image to serve on my local network. NOAA recently tweaked a few things with their xml so my script hasn't updated in a while.

Things run peachy when I manually run the script with sudo. When the cron job runs as www-data I get an error on an unremarkable line of code

```
File "parse_weather.py", line 108, in <module>
    xml_day_one = dom.getElementsByTagName('start-valid-time')[0].firstChild.nodeValue.split('T')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The crontab contains the following

`1 *    * * *   www-data  /var/www/kindle/kindle.sh > /var/www/kindle/kindle.log 2>&1`

I assume it's a permissions issue seeing as the code runs fine manually. Everything in the directory belongs to www-data and all the executables are at least 550 though. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Is it possible you are fetching a resource (via HTTP?) and it's being written somewhere outside your working directory?

Comment: cron wont load up your enviroment when it runs your script. So maybe the python version cron is using isnt the same as the one you use when logged in as a user? or any other enviroment variables that would need set like proxy creentials etc to make http connections

Comment: Save and examine the HTML.  Perhaps the site doesn't like your credentials . . . it would appear the returned result is correct enough to be loaded into a DOM, but is it the same output you get when running manually?

Comment: I'm fetching the page with urllib2. This isn't the first instance that I'm working on the dom though. Everything prior to this line seems to work.

The shell script the cron is running specifies python2.7 so I don't think it's a version issue.

Comment: @FrankMerrow and Chris, dumping the loaded html into a file reveals no difference between a manual run and a run by cron besides the various timestamps in the data.

Comment: So then we are back to @ChrisDoyle's suggestion.  You need to make sure your cron python environment matches your manual environment.  Not just Python versions, but all the modules, environment variables and such as well.

Comment: The next step will be to isolate which of your index access is causing the error. On the xml_day_one line you access 2 lists. I would suggest breaking this into 2 lines. so you can see if the errro comes on getElementsByTagName or split which is causing the index error

Comment: like `first_time = dom.getElementsByTagName('start-valid-time')[0]` and `first_child = first_time.firstChild.nodeValue.split('T')[0]`. that way the stack will be clear which of the two index accessing statements caused the exception

Comment: @ChrisDoyle The code runs without errors as a cron job after splitting the lines. I don't understand why though.

Comment: Well that is indeed bizare since chaining like you were doing is really no difference from splitting the lines. Might it have been a temp issues with the cron or OS? if you join the lines back together and run by cron does the error come back?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle It now seems to work with the original line of code. Really a head scratcher since I changed nothing else. Oh well, thanks for the help!